# Loop through form builder for flat arrays

Tags: angular

I want to list out a flat array via form builder: ie. ["red","blue","yellow"].

I make the form like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            Answers: this.fb.array([])
        });
```

And then I push the flat array to this control like this:

```
this.existingProfileDetail.Answers.forEach(element => {
    (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('Answers')).push(this.fb.control(element));
});
```

And that works fine, but I don't know how to list out the answers on the template, so far I have this:

```
<ol formArrayName="Answers">
                <li class="inputQuestion" *ngFor="let AnswerText of myForm.controls.Answers.controls; let c=index" [formGroupName]="c">
                  <label for="Answer">Answer {{c+1}}</label>
                  <input id="Answer" type="text" formControlName="AnswerText">
                </li>
              </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formGroup has a property called values that you can use to list the answers,

Look for `myForm.values`.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it. You need to omit [formGroupName] and put hard brackets around [formControlName]:

```
<ol formArrayName="Answers">
                <li class="inputQuestion" *ngFor="let answer of myForm.controls.Answers.controls; let i=index">
                  <label for="Answer">Answer {{i+1}}</label>
                  <input id="Answer" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
                </li>
              </ol>
```